# How to Prevent TextWrapping programmatically?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I **prevent a TextView**, or any visual object, **from wrapping** to the screen and instead have them cropped **programmatically**? 
I have a table view which is loaded with TextViews as cells. I **need to crop the text inside the textview instead of wrapping**.
Is there some code to do this? or is there any workaround?

For example, I have like this:

[image: Text Wrapped]

But what I want is:

[image: Cropped Text]

Comment: try to use android:singleLine="true"

Comment: I know it can be done via xml. But I need to do it programatically. How can I acheive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own way to fix this. I set the textView.SetMaxLines to 1 and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setSingleLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28%29) method:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(...);
textView.setSingleLine(true);
```

and [`setEllipsize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29) to remove ellipsize:

```
textView.setEllipsize(null);
```

Comment: Hi ziem, 
this works for me except in few cases. When I set Gravity as left or top for my text view it works great. However on setting the Gravity as center or right, the text in my text view is gone. I dont know why.